# How can keep notification in notification area/ bar if device shutdown?

Tags: android, notifications, notification-area

I am trying to implement push notifications and I got notifications too. But now I need to notifications in notification bar when switched on. I.e. if I got notification when mobile is on at time we did not see notification that is in notification area, if device shutdown then when I switched on the mobile, at time need to get that notification on notification bar and I have also another requirement, i.e. if I remove notification in notification area then after 10 minutes I need get that notification in notification area/ bar.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to save notification content some where such as [SharePreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).
2. You listen when device booted by using this intent, "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED", when broadcast receiver get fired, you read notication content from step 1, fire notification again.

Easy, right :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PendingIntent with **FLAG_ONE_SHOT** :

```
private void sendNotification(String from, String message) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("INFO", bundle);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(from)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
```

And remember set WAKE_LOCK permission in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: no, its not working.its not poping up on notification area after power on

Answer (score 0):

To do stuff on boot register a `BroadcastReceveiver` to `BOOT_COMPLETED` in your manifest.

To do stuff after a certain time use `AlarmManager`.

Comment: i am working on GCM push notifications, so what is the relation with alarm Manager and Broadcast Receveiver